# Pandas: load a table into a dataframe with read_sql - `con` parameter and table name

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

In trying to import an sql database into a python pandas dataframe, and I am getting a syntax error. I am newbie here, so probably the issue is very simple.

After downloading sqlite sample chinook.db from http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/ 
and reading pandas documentation, I tried to load it into a pandas dataframe with

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chinook.db')
df = pd.read_sql('albums', conn)
```

where `'albums'` is a table of 'chinook.db' gathered with sqlite3 from command line.

The result is:

```
...
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'albums': near "albums": syntax error
```

I tried variations of the above code to import in an ipython session the tables of the database for exploratory data analysis, with no success.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a documentation/tutorial for newbies with some examples around?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The first param should be a valid `sql` query. eg `"SELECT * FROM albums"` assuming 'albums' is your table name

Comment: did you try with `pandas.read_sql_table(table_name,conn)` ? or if using `read_sql()`, i think you need a query as @ChrisA suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

An example of db connection with SQLAlchemy can be found here:
https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_connect = create_engine('sqlite:///chinook.db') 
df = pd.read_sql('albums', con=db_connect)
print(df)
```

As suggested by @Anky_91, also `pd.read_sql_table` works, as read_sql wraps it.

The issue was the connection, that has to be made with SQLAlchemy and not with sqlite3.

Thanks